# How do I get current route for condition in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
class Router extends Component{
  render(){
return(
<BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <div className = "parent">
              <LeftNavigator />
              <div className = "page">
                <Route exact path = "/" component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/forum" component = {Forum} />
                <Route path = "/items" component = {Items} />
                <Route path = "/map" component = {Maps} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I want the left navigator to only display if it routes to home, items and maps. If it route to forums, I dont want my left navigator to be displayed. How cab I accomplish this?

I guess I can just copy and paste Left Navigator inside Home, Items and Maps, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use a Route to render `<LeftNavigator/>`. The `path` prop accepts an array of strings that are different paths. In this case, it should look like: `path={['/home','/items','/map']}`

```
class Router extends Component{
  render(){
return(
<BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <div className = "parent">
              <Route path={['/home','/items','/map']}><LeftNavigator /></Route>
              <div className = "page">
                <Route exact path = "/" component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/forum" component = {Forum} />
                <Route path = "/items" component = {Items} />
                <Route path = "/map" component = {Maps} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```